# Desktop Windows Composition and Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: windows-8.1

I stumbled upon a problem when switching from Windows 7 x64 to Windows 8.1 Pro x64.
I have the EXACT same setup, same laptop, same hardware, same programs, same configuration, everything.
Windows 7 never did anything like the problem I now have in Win 8.1. Here's the problem;

Whenever I run more than 1 3D application, after 1-5 minutes the screen blinks, and hangs the graphics of one, some or all the programs (randomly). It doesn't hang the actual program (or game), it just stops rendering the graphics -- I can still hear the software's sound and if I click around, I can hear myself interacting with it.
I have ALL the latest drivers for the computer, motherboard, ALL devices including graphics cards etc. Also ALL Windows Updates installed, nothing more to install.

All of the programs I use is specifically set to use only the nVidia adapter, forcibly through the nVidia Control Panel, so it's not a switching graphics problem because it's a laptop. Also, never was a problem in Windows 7 either. I checked all the other threads about this, but it wasn't relevant to my specific problem.

Here's what I gathered from event viewer right when it happened;

```
A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.
Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       PIXIELIGHT$
    Account Domain:     HYPERUNKNOWN
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
    Account Name:       DWM-1
    Account Domain:     Window Manager
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

.

```
An account was successfully logged on.
Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       PIXIELIGHT$
    Account Domain:     HYPERUNKNOWN
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
Logon Type:         2
Impersonation Level:        Impersonation
New Logon:
    Security ID:        Window Manager\DWM-1
    Account Name:       DWM-1
    Account Domain:     Window Manager
    Logon ID:       0x412659B
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x304
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe
```

.

```
Special privileges assigned to new logon.
Subject:
    Security ID:        Window Manager\DWM-1
    Account Name:       DWM-1
    Account Domain:     Window Manager
    Logon ID:       0x412659B
Privileges:     SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
            SeAuditPrivilege
            SeImpersonatePrivilege
```

.

```
An account was logged off.
Subject:
    Security ID:        Window Manager\DWM-1
    Account Name:       DWM-1
    Account Domain:     Window Manager
    Logon ID:       0x3E3290A
Logon Type:         2
```

.

So as you can see, DWM is logging in and out some account that can be all the way up to DWM-7 from what I've seen so far. It just logs in, sets some parameters and the directly logs out.
This is a ONE-user system, Only my user account is on it, and remote login has been disabled.
In Windows 7, at least DWM could be disabled - not that I ever had to, because it worked with all my stuff, but seeing as DWM is screwing up totally in Win8, I thought I'd just disable the server, but it's nowhere to be found.
Also, it seems Microsoft changed how it works, the system has been redesigned to generate an OK even if it's still on, like this example below:

*DwmEnableComposition( DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION ) does not work on Windows 8, even though it returns S_OK.  Confirmation is by calling DwmIsCompositionEnabled(), which shows the former function had no effect.*

There's only 1 dwm.exe running.
There's only 1 user logged in (me).
There's only 1 user in the userlist (administrative tools -> computer management) except for the Administrator account.

Running only 1 of the softwares at a time is not an option for me, either for work or for home use, so how can I fix this?

Comment: DWM can't be disabled without hacks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of information sharing, I just thought I'd post the resolution.
I didn't have time to experiment with this at all for another 2 weeks but then I eventually solved it.
Solution:

Set all the games to use the nvidia card.
Set all processes that has to do with obs/open broadcaster to use the integrated intel card.
Problem solved, with full FPS everywhere.